# Send particular variable to a function

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to send only the variable you want to a function?
for example i have this function

```
function upload_file($field = "thumbnail",$types = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf',$folder = "",$size = '0',$w = '0',$h = '0', $enc = false)
    {
        if ($folder == "")
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = './Media/uploads/';
        }
        else
        {
            if (!is_dir("./Media/uploads/$folder/"))
            {
                  mkdir("./Media/uploads/$folder/");
            }
            $config['upload_path'] = "./Media/uploads/$folder/";
        }
        $config['allowed_types'] = $types;
        $config['max_size'] = $size;
        $config['max_width']  = $w;
        $config['max_height']  = $h;
        $config['encrypt_name']  = $enc;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r($error);

            return array(false,$error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            return array(true,$data);
        }
    }
```

and i want to use it like this

from the set variables that are contained in

```
function upload_file($field = "thumbnail",$types = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf',$folder = "",$size = '0',$w = '0',$h = '0', $enc = false)
```

i want to set $enc = false into $enc = true by using this

```
$data = $this->base_model->upload_file();
```

is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: Why don't you put `$enc = true` in the function profile? That way `$this->base_model->upload_file();` will provide what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you just set `$enc = true` in the function profile? That way `$this->base_model->upload_file();` will provide what you want

or just simple set the parameters again with `$enc = true`

`$data = $this->base_model->upload_file("thumbnail",'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf',"",'0','0','0',true);`

Comment: this works but its just too long to type. maybe theres some kind of shortcut where $enc is the only one that will change

Comment: @itsover9000 its the only option. else put other values as `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

If merely changing the function signature so that the default `$enc = true` isn't what you're aiming for (as in, normally you want the default to remain `false`) but you don't want to overwrite any other defaults in the function definition in your call by repeating them again (in case they change in the definition as you develop, etc.), then pass `null` values for those parameters:

```
$data = $this->base_model->upload_file( null, null, null, null, null, null, true );
```

Any null parameters are effectively "not passed" and thus the function adopts the default value as defined in the signature. The last parameter is passed `true` to the `$enc` variable, and is thus the only one not the default.